# Problem with AngularJS and jQuery libraries in Ubuntu SDK - HTML 5 App

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk, html5, javascript

I'm trying to explore the "Ubuntu SDK" and just to test I made a "HTML 5 App".
The app need to use angular library (such as: angular.min.js), jQuery library, and angular module for routing (angular-route.min.js), with this module I can fill an index page with other html views, but it doesn't work, it seems that it cannot find the angular libraries. 
Also, after installing it on my Meizu MX4 (with click package kit: all) the problem remain the same.

I checked this link https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/html-5/guides/introduction-to-the-html5-ui-toolkit/ without finding any solution.

Anyone has my same issue? Where am I wrong?

Thank you

Comment: have you tried to read next document - [Cordova guide](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/html-5/guides/cordova-guide/) ?

Comment: Hi @silpol

thank you for your answer. 
I read this page: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/html-5/guides/html5-guide/ and I think that I have problem with "web container". 
In ubuntu webapp it seems possible to use JavaScript, so I don't understand why AngularJS don't work.

Comment: Also, you can find here: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/html-5/guides/introduction-to-the-html5-ui-toolkit/ that it's possible to use external libraries, like jQuery.

But in my own case the import don't work. Maybe it's a problem with libraries version?

Comment: Hi,

**I have solved my issue.** The problem was caused from the library version of AngularJS. I have changed the library, and now all works fine.

Thank you.

Comment: oh, then publish it in the answer edit box down there and push "Post your answer" button - you will get also some special flair for answering own question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have solved my issue.** The problem was caused from the library version of AngularJS. I have changed the library, and now all works fine.

Thank you.